# Is there an option to prevent some values from being displayed in django autocomplete widget?

Tags: django, jquery-autocomplete

I am using django-autocomplete in my "edit user details view" for adding "friends"

django-autocomplete works perfect but displays also the "current user" (who is editing his profile) and the user "anonymous"

I want to exclude those two.

How can I accomplish that?

---

models.py

```
class Profile(UserenaLanguageBaseProfile):
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='userfriends', blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'friends': MultipleAutocompleteWidget(Profile.friends),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete answer, but you should do something along those lines:

```
autocomplete = AutocompleteView()

class ProfileAutocomplete(AutocompleteSettings):
    queryset = Profile.objects.exclude(friends='anonymous')

    autocomplete.register(Profile.friends, UserAutocomplete)
```

But this will not exclude the current user. To get that you will have override/extend the `view` method of your `ProfileAutocomplete` class. In this method you will need to get the user ID (probably from the session) and then exclude it from the queryset. If using the session is not working (it's possible, I didn't put too much time on it), you 'll probably have to modify the `jquery_autocomplete.js` script to pass the user to the `view` method.